# Nonconst lvalue reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, this, rvalue

I am creating an undirected graph an every time I add a neighbour A to a node B I have to add node B as a neghbour of A as well but my approach does not work.

`Non-const lvalue reference to type 'Element *' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Element *'`

```
class Element
{
    std::vector<Element *> m_neighbours;
private:

public:
    void addNeighbour(Element*& neighbour)
    {
        m_neighbours.push_back(neighbour);
        neighbour->addNeighbour(this);
    }
};
```

1. What is happening?
2. Best way to solve it?

Comment: What's the motivation to `emplace_back` a pointer rather than just `push_back` it?

Comment: Passing the pointer by reference also seems like a code smell to me, especially since it is not changing within the function.

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: But if I do not pass it by reference in theorey I have a copy so when calling addNeighbour I would not be calling the real neighbour isnt it?

Comment: remove the `&` to fix it

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos You will have a copy *of the pointer*, not a copy of *the thing being pointed at.*

Answer (score 1):

To understand what the issue is, let's imagine that you wrote this code instead:

```
void addNeighbour(Element*& neighbour)
{
    m_neighbours.emplace_back(neighbour);
    neighbour->addNeighbour(this);
    neighbour = nullptr; // <--- This is new
}
```

Now, think about what happens when you make this call:

```
neighbour->addNeighbour(this);
```

The call to the function passes in `this` by reference, meaning "please, feel free to reassign `this`." And then in the function call, the last line, indeed, tries to reassign `neighbour` to `nullptr`. But that's a problem, because you can't write

```
this = nullptr; // Error!
```

because `this` is an rvalue.

The easiest fix here would be to not take the parameter by reference, since you aren't doing anything to it where you'd actually need the reference. Just take in an `Element*`, saying "please hand me a copy of the pointer you're interested in."

(Independently - your code will get you into trouble because calling `A->addNeighbour(B)` will call `B->addNeighbour(A)`, which calls `A->addNeighbour(B)`, which calls `B->addNeighbour(A)`, etc. until you blow out your call stack. You should add a check in here to make sure that, if the `Element` already is recorded, you don't add it a second time. You may want to make `m_neighbours` a `std::unordered_set` rather than a `std::vector` for that purpose.)

Comment: When you are trying to change what the pointer points to inside a function, you might take a reference to it. Although you also would want a good reason to not just use a return instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` pointer [is defined to be a prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this), and your function takes an `lvalue`. The language forbids that sort of binding [for various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). You're not modifying the given pointer, so just pass it by value instead of by reference.

```
void addNeighbour(Element* neighbour);
```

instead of

```
void addNeighbour(Element*& neighbour);
```